# Automatically adjust a clock that measures time worked in 100 minutes vs 60 minutes

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, time, string-formatting, number-formatting

The aim is to automatically adjust a clock that measures time worked in 100 minutes vs 60 minutes. For example, the timesheet may show 21:76 hours which would be 21 hours and 46 minutes when converted to a standard 60-minute clock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ":", ".")/24, "hh:mm")
```

[image]

or:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1; ":"; ",")/24; "hh:mm")
```